# How to make effect behind the picture?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

How to make effect behind the picture? Like you can see in the picture. and of course image have to be responsive.

[image: effect behind the image]

Comment: and of course you do not share any code of your attempts and failure :) SO is to help, not a free coding service even if it is full of lovely members ; . You probably misread https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one line solution:

```css
img {
 padding:20px;
 background:linear-gradient(transparent 40px,red 0 calc(100% - 40px),transparent 0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate an effect like this by utilising absolute positioning with a relative parent.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.imageWrapper {
  background: rebeccapurple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 16px;
}

.imageWrapper img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageWrapper">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/180/220" alt="">
</div>
```

Ignore the `body` styles, they are just to illustrate the point better in the preview. The `.imageWrapper` and `.imageWrapper img` are the things you want to pay attention to.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. In this code, we have given position relative to the `img-block` and gave background color in it's `pseudo-element` with position absolute.

```css
.img-block {
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-block:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  background: #F9CDF1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.img-block img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/490x590.png" alt="image" />
</div>
```